# MediaPlayer seekTo doesn't work

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

If I call seekTo before start, an audio starts from beginning.

Is it possible to start playing audio from a specific point?

Thanks!

Comment: seekTo() shold be called after prepared, do you call seekTo() in MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.onPrepared

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug on Android platform, and so far it hasn't been fixed.
[See this issue here.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9135)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can reproduce it on Android Jelly Bean.

Comment: I've looked forward for it a bit and it looks like a serious bug. Didn't find any solution or explanation why it doesn't work.
[See this another issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4124)
As you can see at the bottom of the page "Still happens on Galaxy Nexus running Jelly Bean.." But it was at 2012 Oct, so I don't know, maybe you can try to write for the android developers.

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced the same issue. The solution was to use `MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener`.

However in my case there weren't any problems with calling `seekTo` before `start` if the audio file was relatively short, but if it became longer then it seemed that starting the playback occurred earlier than `seekTo` was finished.