# Android MediaPlayer SeekTo function workaround

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am creating a very simple media player app. I would like to resume  the song from the SeekTo position that I have captured using getCurrentPosition. However seekTo does not start from the position I have captured but from the beginning.

Code to capture current position, pause and change button text to Click to resume

```
int media_length = mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
    Toast.makeText(this,"media length is"+media_length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mbutton.setText("Click to Resume");
    mediaplayer.pause();
```

Code to seekTo captured position, start and change button text to Click to Pause

```
    mediaplayer.seekTo(media_length);
    mediaplayer.start();
    mbutton.setText("Click to Pause");
```

A couple of posts are there already related to it but they seem to claim a bug in Android. 
Ref: [MediaPlayer seekTo doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678027/mediaplayer-seekto-doesnt-work) and 
is there any workaround for this? appreciate any help.

Comment: If you look at the documentation here:

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try below code. It is working for me...

```
public void forwardSong() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        int currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mPlayer.getDuration()) {
            mPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
        } else {
            mPlayer.seekTo(mPlayer.getDuration());
        }
    }
}
```

You can pause mediaplayer before this and just call start method after this method.

Comment: I tried this code you have mentioned and it works now. The song resumes from the exact position where I had paused it earlier. Thank you Sanket for your help.

Comment: If it is working then please accept this as a answer so others can take benefit of it... Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the callback MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener.

Important : In this sample, i've added `SystemClock.sleep(200)` because `onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer arg0)` is called too soon by the player BEFORE seekTo is really completed.

```
 mMediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSeekComplete() current pos : " + arg0.getCurrentPosition());
            SystemClock.sleep(200);
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(mCurrentPos);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e){
        Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Dany - Is there a reason for this delay in the Android documentation anywhere. I am experiencing the issue, but this is the only thread online I can see a reference to it. In addition, after the mediaPlayer finally does update its position, the position is the beginning of the media file (as opposed to my desired seekto position).

Answer (score 0):

### Try this , it works

```
   videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
            mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```