# Why MediaPlayer does not work SeekTo

Tags: java, android

Why MediaPlayer does not work SeekTo .
SeekTo More precisely, it works, but if you add SeekTo (5000) or SeekTo  (10000).

But if you do this. SeekTo (1000) or SeekTo (3563) then nothing will work.
Then MediaPlayer starts playing video from 0. Why is it so? And how to fix it.

Comment: You should post an example of your code that shows what you are trying to do so that people don't have to get at what you're asking. This is also an expectation when you ask a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20088887/1656813), this code may work:

```
public void forwardSong() {
if (mPlayer != null) {
    int currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mPlayer.getDuration()) {
        mPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
    } else {
        mPlayer.seekTo(mPlayer.getDuration());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: seekForwardTime What's this?. SeekBar or Integer?

Comment: its the time you want to start from. for example 2000