# MediaPlayer pause current song, play another and go back & resume

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how to pause a determined song, store its contents so it is possible to load a different song, play that new song and restore the saved content from the first song and resume it.

The only way I was able to manage that was to create a `List<MediaPlayer>` list so every new song has their own instance of the `MediaPlayer`.

Is there a better way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a List of MediaPlayer objects. It should be possible to do it with one. However you will have to take care of its state.

It could work something like this:
You can get the current time when you start playing the first song. Once you start the second song, you can get the current time again and calculate the difference in milliseconds. Once the second song finishes (use a `OnCompletionListener`), you can load the first song again and use the `seekTo(long milliseconds)` method of the `MediaPlayer` to go back where you stopped.

You will obviously have to manage the state of the media player, but this shouldn't be a problem.
You can take a look here for a good documentation and a nice state diagram: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: But if I do that, the `MediaPlayer` will download again the song. It is an online streaming.

Comment: well, seekTo should take care of this, actually. However, there might be an android related bug. You can investigate if that is still unresolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678027/mediaplayer-seekto-doesnt-work

Also take a look at this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4124